# Firefox add <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-namespaces

EDIT: This isn't happening because of the ajax call.  I changed it to use a value from a TinyMCE component for fun and I get the same thing.

```
content = tinyMCE.get('cComponent').getContent(); //content at this point is <p>test</p>
valueToDisplay = content;
```

If I do:

```
jQuery(selector).html(valueToDisplay);
```

I get:

```
<p><a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">test</a></p>
```

---

Has anyone ever seen this before using Firefox 3.6.10 and jQuery 1.4.2, I am trying to change a link text using the result from a jQuery ajax call.

I get the result expected from the ajax call:

```
function getValueToDisplay(fieldType){
    var returnValue;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "index.cfm",
        async:false, 
        data: "fieldtype="+fieldType,
        success:function(response){
            returnValue = response;
    }                   
    });
    return returnValue;
   }
```

If I check the value at this point I get the expected value

```
console.log(returnValue) //output this --> <p>Passport Photo</p>
```

However when I use jQuery(selector).html to insert it inside of an existing anchor

I get:

```
<p><a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Passport Photo</a></p>
```

I have been trying to figure out where that xmlns anchor is added but can't narrow it down to anything specific.

EDIT: I have tried forcing dataType:"html" in the ajax call...no change.

Comment: What does the content of index.cfm look like? Also, why not just use the .load() function with your target as index.cfm?fieldtype=foo

Comment: @dave index.cfm with that query string has nothing in it but the output of a loop over a recordset.  No <html> or anything... could that be why?

Comment: I changed it to getJSON and the html function still add the xmlns anchor around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector represents something that is, or is in an `a` tag.

A much more minimal version of your problem would be:

html:

```
<a id="test"></a>
```

js:

```
$('#test').html('<p>test</p>');
```

result:

```
<a id="test"><p><a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">test</a></p></a>
```

Change things around so you aren't putting `p` tags in an `a` tag, or do the following:

```
$('#test').empty().append('<p>test</p>');
```

Comment: +1 That would explain why using jQuery(selector).html(function(index,oldHtml){ return valueToDisplay; }); is working as it clear it out.  Thanks for the much simpler explanation.  I guess using a <p> inside an anchor isn't exactly good anyway.  Still I find the documentation for .html() a little misleading (as it shouldn't be changing the parameter).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to extend the answer, as of why is happening, and provide a workaround.
Doing a GreaseMonkey script i was trying to change the content of an  element, perhaps not changing per se but adding more elements as the tag had only an IMG inside.

Original:

```
<a onclick=something><img src=url></a>
```

What i tried to do was to insert a DIV element that would wrap the already IMG and another new SPAN second child, so the objetive was to end up with this:

```
<a onclick=something><div><img src=url><span>text</span></div></a>
```

Using the innerHTML property it would be like this:

```
ANode.innerHTML = '<div>' + ANode.innerHTML + '<span>text</span></div>';
```

but instead i got:

```
<a onclick=something><div><a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><img src=url><span>text</span></a></div></a>
```

Looking at the answers here did help a bit although there's no real explanation. After a while i noticed something that does not happens with the example in the question, which now i believe is the key to this issue. I was the same as jfrobishow thinking where was it happening, i thought there was something wrong concatenating the ANode.innerHTML.

Answering, at the original question, the part of narrowing it down to where does this happens, notice that the out-of-nowhere `<A>` was enclosing both the IMG and the new SPAN nodes, so this made me curious, the unwanted `<A>` was being added just before the DIV element was "built". So from this, the original example, and my following workaround you can notice that this happens when you insert a new BLOCK node inside an Anchor, as both DIV and P (original example) elements are BLOCK elements.

(If you don't know what i mean by BLOCK is from the display property of an element http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

The obvious workaround is to replace the type of node you're inserting, to a non-block element, in my case the problem was the DIV i wanted, but of course it depends on the objective of your script, most of the things are there by design, i put a DIV because i needed it, so i fixed it turning that DIV into another SPAN ( which is an inline element) but i still needed to behave like a block element so put the style, this is what worked for me:

```
ANode.innerHTML = '<span style="display:block;">' + ANode.innerHTML + '<span>text</span></span>';
```

So, plainly, this problem is not from scripting (Javascript for me) but from style (CSS) stuff.
BTW, this happened at Firefox 3.6.18, notice this does not happens at Firefox 5.0.

Comment: +1 good workaround using an inline element and forcing the display:block if that's what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is placing block elements inside an anchor tag.
This is not valid HTML, even though most browsers will parse it fine.

You just need to use a `<span></span>` element inside the anchor, instead of a `<div>` or `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in your `<html>` you declared a XML Namespace (xmlns).  If the xmlns anchor is not breaking anything, just leave it there.

Also, don't use `async:false`, make a callback function to be called on success.

Comment: Good point but I am not using any namepsace in the html tag for this app.  This is the header - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html debug="true">

Comment: Firefox probably is adding it for you because there isn't one there.
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: @dave if I read the spec correctly the xmlns is only required if the document is xhtml. This should tell the browser it isn't no? <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> based on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Actually that just fixed the issue with that particular value... it started happening on other values where it used to be fine.

<strike>Somehow this fixed the issue.</strike>

Changed

```
jQuery(selector).html(valueToDisplay)
```

to

```
jQuery(selector).html(
    function(index, oldHtml)  
    {
        return valueToDisplay;
    }
);
```

According to the doc, if I read it right it should be doing the same thing as I am not using oldHtml in the function. (http://api.jquery.com/html/).

> From the doc: "jQuery empties the element before calling the function; use the oldhtml argument to reference the previous content."

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `dataType` in your ajax call to `"text"`

Comment: it's not coming from the ajax request.  I was able to reproduce it with values accessed directly from TinyMCE.  It's not constant, but appears to be coming from jQuery.html(string)

Answer (score 0):

Using .append() instead of .html() fixed the issue for me.  Never seen this before today.  Why is it adding the extra xmlns?  I tried changing my dataType to "text" as well, but it didn't work.  It was really messing up my CSS styles as well, but using .append() completely resolved the issue. Thanks!

**UPDATE**:  I needed to completely replace the content of my div with the result of an .ajax() query.  .append() by itself wasn't sufficient, as it would just add to the content, so I found another workaround:

First clear the div:

```
$("#myDiv").html("");
```

Then, append the content using .append():

```
$("#myDiv").append("My content");
```

It's not perfect, but it works.

Comment: are you doing like I was initially? using <p> tag inside of anchors?