# jquery "html" function returns weird behaviour

Tags: jquery

i used jquery "html" function:

```
$('#color .updateMoney').html('1');
```

to replace a certain string but instead it replace the content with an anchor wrapping like this:

```
<a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">1</a>
```

Why is that so?

Comment: can you show the entire code for the page

Comment: Have you tried `text('1')` instead of `html()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a similiar thread: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736474/firefox-add-a-xmlnshttp-www-w3-org-1999-xhtml)

Apparently it seems to be a firefox problem. I used

`$('#color .updateMoney').empty().append('1');`

instead to solve the problem.