# find a specific word and wrap with a span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am not sure the best way to go about this. here is the problem. i have a menu (list items) that has an irregular pattern of display. i cant alter the html directly as it is being spit out of a cms. i would like it so that if a word in an array matches a word in the link then that word has a span wrapped around it.
this is that code simplified:

```
<li class="item1"><a href="gosomewhere.html">About My Store</a></li>
<li class="item2"><a href="gosomewhereelse.html">Find Locations</a></li>
```

result i want is this:

```
<li class="item1"><a href="gosomewhere.html"><span class="bigwords">About My </span>Store</a></li>
<li class="item2"><a href="gosomewhere.html">Find <span class="bigwords">Locations</span></a></li>
```

i can find the first word(s) doing this:

```
      $(function() {
    $.fn.wrapStart = function (numWords) {
    var node = this.contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3 }).first(),
        text = node.text(),
        first = text.split(" ", numWords).join(" ");

    if (!node.length)
        return;

    node[0].nodeValue = text.slice(first.length);
    node.before('<span class="bigwords">' + first + '</span>');
};


$("li.item1 a").wrapStart(1);
```

however, what i would like to do is look through an array list and wrap those specific words that i want  in whatever position they occur.

the array would be like about, store, faq...

the script would look for those words and wrap them...

not really sure how to go about this. if its easier. since the big words only occur either at the beginning or the end but not in middle... i could have another function that looks for the last word(s).

there are only 5 menu  items (wont change) and the words will never change, which is why i thought of just using an array...

here is the output i get of the plugin use:

```
<ul class="menu><li class="item-102 parent">
<a class="about" title="About my store" href="#">
<span class="bigwords">
<a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">About</a>
</span>
<a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> my store</a>
</a>
</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a simple plugin recently that could accomplish this:

(it no longer exists)

you would use it like this:

```
var arr = ["about my","locations"];
$.each(arr,function(i,word){
  $(".items").highlightText(word,"bigwords",true)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4gtmH/23/

Since i'm using a regexp, you could also do it this way:

```
$(".items").highlightText("about my|locations","bigwords",true)
```

Also:

I used .items as a class because in my example i gave the ul a class of items. you can supply any selector and it will highlight all text within the element and it's children.

Here's the part of the plugin that does the work, just in case that link goes dead for some reason:

```
$(this).find("*").andSelf().contents()

// filter to only text nodes that aren't already highlighted
.filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $(this).closest("." + hClass).length === 0;
})

// loop through each text node
.each(function () {
    var output;
    output = this.nodeValue.replace(re, "<" + defaultTagName + " class='" + hClass + "'>$1</" + defaultTagName + ">");
    if (output !== this.nodeValue) {
        $(this).wrap("<p></p>").parent()
            .html(output).contents().unwrap();
    }
});
```

Comment: so this is great... but it is producing some extra <a> tags around the text. you can see it if you look in the fiddle you posted.

Comment: what browser? i'm not seeing extra anchor tags in chrome. And.. doesn't seem to be working in IE.

Comment: the ie issue seems to be related to jsfiddle, it isn't including the plugin code.

Comment: can't see any extra `<a>` ... All ok! Go for it! Tentonaxe +1!

Comment: yes its doing this in ff and jsfiddle. it seems to cause style issues with element... i will add the code to my post...

Comment: hmm... i've seen this before, but i forget what causes it... what doctype are you using?

Comment: a quick fix to the extra a tag issue would be `$(".menu").find("a[xmlns]").children().unwrap()` but i would like to be able to prevent it from within the plugin if possible. Also, i'm not seeing this behavior in Firefox 6

Comment: proofing in an older version of Firefox... xhtml 1.0 transitional. it would be nice to get a better fix than than the unwrap, but i will take it :-)

Comment: here's a post about this issue, i'll try to implement it into the plugin when i get a chance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736474/firefox-add-a-xmlns-http-www-w3-org-1999-xhtml

Comment: Is there any way to wrap word which is immediate before "store" word?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this [jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)? Haven't used it myself but looks like it does the job pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a jquery selector on all elements and foreach result in the selector set the val with the val replaced with  and the data