# Javascript (jQuery) … filter for a character within a text inside a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, filter, character

what is the best solution and how would you do that.

I have this on my site …

```
<div class="desc">
   <p>
   Some text that is set via a CMS and is completely dynamic. 
   It contains sometimes a character like this § in the middle of the text.
   It could also contain another one §, you see!
   </p>
</div>
```

I wonder how I can filter this text for the character `§` and wrap it inside of a span.

`<span class="symbol">§</span>`

Any ideas on that? I don't want to decrease a lot of performance on my site when doing this.

Thank you in advance,
Matt

Comment: possible duplicate of [find a specific word and wrap with a span tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325463/find-a-specific-word-and-wrap-with-a-span-tag)

Comment: A remark on the answer you selected: Note that it destroys any element that is inside the paragraph (for example links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".desc p").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/§/g, "<span class=\"symbol\">§</span>"))
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kjTDw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

`findAndReplaceDOMText` is a great library for doing this and much more (if you need the functionality).

> findAndReplaceDOMText searches for regular expression matches in a DOM node and wraps all matches (and portions of matches separated by node bounderies) with a specified element.

Github: https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText
Demo: http://padolsey.github.com/findAndReplaceDOMText/demo.html

It matches strings using regular expression and it will automagically work for strings spread across multiple nodes:

```
<p id="t">
   123 456 99<span>9 foo</span>
</p>

findAndReplaceDOMText(/9+/, document.getElementById('t'), 'em');
```

This would result in:

```
<p id="t">
   123 456 <em>99</em><span><em>9</em> foo</span>
</p>
```

(Example from https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText/blob/master/readme.md)

Answer (score 0):

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uYZ78/)

```
$('p').each(function () {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\$/g, '<span>$</span>'));
});​
```

Comment: You need to use `$(this).html()` otherwise the `<span>` tag will be HTML encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I would find all paragraphs containing the `§` symbol (no need to match every paragraph), wrapping every occurrence of that symbol

```
$(".desc p:contains('§')").each(function() {
   $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/§/g, '<span class="symbol">§</span>'));   
})
```